# Basic Help w/ Poisson Processes + Marginal Distributions

Tags: calculus, statistics

There are two companies, Company $1$ and Company $2$. Stock market crashes occur according to a poisson process with rate $\lambda_0$ and destroy both. A type $k$ event also follows a poisson process with rate $\lambda_1$($\lambda_2$) and destroys only Company $k$ for $k: \{1,2\}$. All three poisson processes are independent. Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be how long Company $1$ and Company $2$ will survive.

(a) Find the marginal distribution of $X_1$ and $X_2$.

(b) Find $P(X_1>x_1,X_2>x_2)$,  and use this to find the joint CDF of $X_1$ and $X_2$.

Alright, for (a) you get that $X_1$ is $\sim \operatorname{Expo}(\lambda_0 + λ_1$) and $X_2$ is $\sim \operatorname{Expo}(\lambda_0 + \lambda_2$).

Are these right? How do I go about #$2$?

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

Let $C$ denote the time until market crash event.

Let $W_1$ denote the time until a type $1$ event.

Let $W_2$ denote the time until a type $2$ event.
$$P(X_1 > x, X_2 > x_2) =P(C > \max(x_1,x_2),W_1 >x_1,W_2>x_2) $$

Also note that

$$P(X_1 \leq x_1, X_2 \leq x_2) =1-P(\{X_1 > x_1\} \cup\{X_2>x_2\})$$